# Counts of binned data by group

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, binning

I have continuous data $A$ and categorical data $O$. I need counts of $A$ in bins by group $O$. I'm working in R.

I know how to bin data (using `cut2`) and how to get the counts of $O$ (using `aggregate` or `by` or `describe` or `summaryBy`). I could also get what I need by running one of these functions with a subset (bin) of the data one by one, but is there a way to do this automatically in one command?

**Update:**
The output I want is just basic descriptive statistics (counts in this case, but also means and/or medians for example):

```
Age (A)................Outcome (O)
........................Yes....No
18-27 ...................10....12
28-37 ....................2....11
38-47 ....................9.....7
```

For example:

```
by(subset(X, X$Age>47)$Age, subset(X, X$Age>47)$Outcome, length)
```

gives me the number of data points for ages > 47 where `Outcome` is true and where `O` is false. I want to do this for all bins automatically, without having to run separate commands with long > and < conditions for each bin.

Comment: Could you show a reproducible example of what you can do, and a mock-up of what would you like to achieve? You are mentioning very powerful functions (e.g. `summaryBy`), and most likely you can do what you want with them, but it is hard to understand what you are missing.

Comment: @Aniko: I've updated the question with example output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really like using the `summary.formula` function in the `Hmisc` package for these tasks.

Some artificial data:

```
A <- rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=20)
G <- gl(2, 50)
B <- unclass(G)*10 + rnorm(100, sd=3)
```

Descriptives by `G`:

```
summary( G ~ cut2(A,g=4) + B, method="reverse")

Descriptive Statistics by G    
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|                              |1                            |2                            |
|                              |(N=50)                       |(N=50)                       |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|cut2(A, g = 4) : [ 5.19, 43.0)|           22% (11)          |           28% (14)          |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|    [42.98, 49.7)             |           18% ( 9)          |           32% (16)          |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|    [49.68, 60.3)             |           26% (13)          |           24% (12)          |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|    [60.27,107.5]             |           34% (17)          |           16% ( 8)          |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|B                             | 7.849173/10.153238/11.737293|18.766779/20.155744/22.139419|
+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Summarizing `B` by `G` and ranges of `A` with a custom function:

```
summary(B ~ cut2(A, g=4) + stratify(G), fun=function(x)c(mean(x),sd(x)))
B by g    N=100

+--------------+-------------+--+---------+--------+--+--------+--------+
|              |             |N |         |B       |N |        |B       |
+--------------+-------------+--+---------+--------+--+--------+--------+
|cut2(A, g = 4)|[ 5.19, 43.0)|11|10.351295|3.069181|14|20.55056|3.659311|
|              |[42.98, 49.7)| 9|10.269449|2.460152|16|19.18630|1.628746|
|              |[49.68, 60.3)|13| 9.432093|2.928439|12|21.07909|3.064897|
|              |[60.27,107.5]|17| 9.683748|2.800625| 8|20.65612|2.685183|
+--------------+-------------+--+---------+--------+--+--------+--------+
|Overall       |             |50| 9.870604|2.777788|50|20.25773|2.844987|
+--------------+-------------+--+---------+--------+--+--------+--------+
```

The documentation describes lots of options to control what is calculated and how the output looks like.

Comment: @Aniko: Thanks. I'm working through your answer now. The first `g` in the first formula must be `G`. Why do you have a third data set (`B`), if `A` is your continuous and `G` is your factor/categorical?

Comment: I fixed the problem with `g` - it should have been `G`. I used `B` because I wanted to have a third variable inside the table for the second example. Also, I kept `cut`-ting `A` to make rows of it to mirror your table.

Comment: @Aniko: Thanks. The first part of the answer (after I excluded `B`) is returning what I need. I'm having difficulty getting the mean/media/sd instead of the counts. I don't know how to use the second part of the answer without `B`.

Comment: Do you want the mean/median of A by bins of A? Then just use `A` where I used `B`. I thought that means/medians got to imply the presence of a third variable.

Comment: @Aniko: Yes, I want means, etc. of A by bins of A by outcome. I replaced `B` with `A` but did not get the output I need. I've done it again and this time I think it is giving me what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @Aniko: Please could you indicate how I could get a $\chi^2$ p-value for each of the two outcomes per bin? I need to know if there is a difference in the counts for each of the two outcomes in each bin.  (I've asked Jim as well, as the two solutions are different.)

Comment: @SabreWolfy Look at the `test=TRUE` option in `summary.formula()`.

Comment: @chi: Adding `test=TRUE` (to the first formula above) gives output for the first bin only.

Comment: No, adding `test=TRUE` does not give output for the first bin only, it adds (to the first row) an _overall_ p-value testing whether the distribution across the bins is the same in the two groups. You can control exactly what test is performed (`catTest` parameter) - for example, here you might want to run an ordered test, because the bins are ordered - but it will be one p-value per variable. It does not make sense to do a separate test for each bin.

Answer (score 2):

@SabreWolfy: I've edited my answer to add an additional factor by binning data:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(doBy)
set.seed(123)

A=rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=20)

bin.data<-data.frame(bins.A=cut2(A, g=4),G=gl(2,50), A)

summaryBy(A~bins.A+G,data=bin.data,FUN=each(length,mean,median))
```

will give output for age:

```
        bins.A G A.length   A.mean A.median
1 [ 3.82,40.2) 1       14 29.44193 29.06172
2 [ 3.82,40.2) 2       11 29.41250 29.62849
3 [40.18,51.4) 1       12 44.04858 43.98966
4 [40.18,51.4) 2       13 45.93984 45.48458
5 [51.41,64.0) 1       11 57.00405 58.01543
6 [51.41,64.0) 2       14 57.24880 57.11421
7 [64.03,93.7] 1       13 74.35300 74.15924
8 [64.03,93.7] 2       12 77.01414 75.09460
```

for each combination of the bin factor and the grouping factor.

Comment: @Jim: I'm not sure that this gives me what I need. I want continuous variable A (age) in BINS by categorical G (see example in my question). Your solution groups A by G.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks. The updated version of your answer gives me what I need.

Comment: @Jim: Please could you indicate how I could get a $\chi^2$ p-value for each of the two outcomes per bin? I need to know if there is a difference in the counts for each of the two outcomes in each bin. (I've asked Aniko as well, as the two solutions are different.)

Comment: @Jim Finally, the `Hmisc` library is not needed here?...

Comment: @chl. Sorry for being late in responding. The function `cut2` is in the `Hmisc` library.

Comment: @SabreWolfy, The counts for each of the age classes will depend on how they are binned, thus the differences between Aniko and my answers.

Comment: @Jim My fault! I didn't notice `cut2` :( (+1, btw)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the `Hmisc` package, you can use `table` or `xtabs`:

```
table(cut(X$Age, c(0, 27, 37, 47, 999), X$Outcome)
xtabs(~ cut(Age, c(0, 27, 37, 47, 999) + Outcome, data=X)
```

Comment: Got `table` to work using `cut2`. Couldn't get `xtabs` to work. Thanks for the ideas.